# Does not render template

Tags: javascript, render, lodash

Please, help me to find syntax error in my code, it does not render with loDash.
There must appear modal window with the click on the button with explanation is the choosen answer is correct.

This is html:

```
 <script type="text/template" id="test">
  <div class="wrapper">
  <header><%= header %></header>
  <form action="#" method="POST">
    <ul>
   <% for (var i=0;i<questions.length;i++) {  %>
     <li><h3><%= questions[i].title %></h3>
    <% for (var j=0; j<questions[i].answers.length;j++){ %>
   <p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="<%= questions[i].checkName %>" id="<%= questions[i].id[j]%>"/>
    <label for="<%= questions[i].id[j] %>"<%= questions[i].answers[j]%></label>
    </p>
    <% }; %>
  </li>
  <% };%>
</ul>
   <button>Проверить мои результаты</button>

  </form>
  </div>

  </script>
```

And here is script.js

```
"use strict";

var obj = {

header: "Some test",

questions:[
     {title:"Question №1",
      chekboxName:["one","two","three"],
      id:["1","2","3"],
      answers:["Case №1","Case №2","Case №3"],
      correct:1
      },
     {title:"Question №2",
      chekboxName:["one","two","three"],
     id:["1","2","3"],
      answers:["Case №1","Case №2","Case №3"],
      correct:2
      },
      {title:"Question №3",
      chekboxName:["one","two","three"],
      id:["1","2","3"],
      answers:["Case №1","Case №2","Case №3"],
      correct:3
      }
      ]
      };

var sObj = JSON.stringify(obj);
localStorage.setItem("object", sObj);

var retObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("object"));
var html = $('#test').html();
var content = tmpl(html,retObj);
$("body").append(content);

function showModal(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var modal = $("div class='modal'></div>");
     var result = 0;
     var answer = $('input:checked');
     var correct = [];
     for (var i=0; i<retObj.questions.length;i++){
          correct[i] = retObj.questions[i].correct;
          if($(answer[i]).attr('id')==correct[i]){
               result+=1;
               modal.append('<p class="correct">Answer for '+ (i+1)+'question is correct</p>');
     } else {
          modal.append('<p class="incorrect">Answer for ' + (i+1) + 'question is incorrect</p>');
     }
}
modal.append('<button>Try again</button>');
$('body').append(modal);

$('button').one('click',function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     modal.detach();
     $('input').attr('checked', false);
```

Comment: chekboxName is an array

Comment: create a plunker or fiddle it will help to fix

Comment: Here is link for plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/3hzJzYxMOJv4YoGjgC7m?p=preview